# How to unset header field in a view in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have put a "Global:link" in the header of a view in Drupal 7. I suppose I could put the link as html in a Global:text area as well.
If the user is not admin I don't want them to see this link. So I have tried to put this code in my themes template.php:

```
// hide global text area in view header if user is not admin
function mytheme_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if ($view->name == 'taxonomy_term') {
        dpm($view->name);
        global $user;
      // Check to see if $user has the administrator role or not.
        if (!in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
                $header_item = $view->display_handler->get_option('header');
                dpm($header_item['link']);
                unset($header_item['link']);

    }
        }
    }
}
```

.. but how do I unset a global field in the header of this specific view?
My code above does not do the trick.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I finally solved it. Here's the snippet. Hope it helps somebody having the same issue. Change "link" to whatever item you use in the header:

```
function mytheme_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    if ($view->name == 'taxonomy_term') {
        global $user;
        $new_item = $view->get_item('page', 'header', 'link');
        $new_item['text'] = "";
      // Check to see if $user has the administrator role or not.
        if (!in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
            $view->set_item('page', 'header', 'link', $new_item);
        }
    }
```